# 2NF database Normalization

Tags: mysql, database, normalization, database-normalization

Good Day-

I'm working on the task in which I have to create the data model on the basis of the following information.

> Your task is to create the model for storing the following
>   information: A list of albums and
>       the album art for each (image files), the tracks for one album, the band’s record label or labels, their
>       genre, and the band members.

I have created five tables so far. And I have to cover the Normalization part But I'm confused with it.One of table I have created has the following columns and data.

**bandMember**

1. bandMemberId - auto increment
2. bandladelId - FK
3. realname
4. nickname
5. memberphoneNo
6. memberRole
7. memberActive
8. memberdob
9. memberAge

and this table has the following data so far.

[image]

for resolving this I have removed the comma separated values and add each row for the data. Now it's look like this.

[image]

Could someone please guide me How can I split this table and remove this problem (If Normalization Exist)? Because I'm also confused with the primary key here. The examples which are referred on Internet is based on Age column. But I'm not getting those examples. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you specifically required to create a 2NF layout? If not, 3NF is generally the "best" level of normalization to target, and the easiest to deal with.

Comment: @MarcB specifically I have to required to create all 3 layers of Normalization. Thanks

Comment: @MarcB 3NF is no more the best level of normalization than 3rd gear is the best gear to drive in.  Rather than harp on one normal form, try to understand dependencies and anomalies.

Answer (score 0):

Your step to split the row with a multivalued attribute into multiple rows looks almost like the step to resolve repeating groups to achieve 1NF.  However, in that transformation, each new row gets a *copy* of the corresponding values in the original.  Your auto-increment column incremented for the new row, and hence your 2nd table is a different problem, and not a 1NF version of the first.

The 1st table, transformed to 1NF, would have 2 rows, both with `bandMemberId` values of 1 and using `(bandMemberId, memberRole)` as a candidate key.  Since all the non-prime attributes depend on only `bandMemberId`, that's a partial dependency.  Copying `(bandMemberId, memberRole)` to a separate table and removing `memberRole` from the `bandMember` table would give us a 2NF schema.  You don't give any functional dependencies so I'm not sure if the schema is in 3NF as well.